# CSS Background parameters trouble

Tags: css

```
background : url(../images/li.png) no-repeat 0 50%;
```

what parameters are 0 and 50%? they are not specified explicitly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `background` property is shorthand for:

- `background-color`
- `background-image`
- `background-repeat`
- `background-attachment`
- `background-position`

The `0 50%` is the `background-position`.

See this awesome website for details: http://www.htmldog.com/reference/cssproperties/background/

Answer (score 1):

This is the position.
0 50% would be left middle (0% on left-position, 50% of top-position).

You can check the spec for more info : http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/colors.html